# How to get tab pane tabs rotated and visible when oriented on the left side?

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently trying to get the tabs on the tab pane to be rotated 90 degrees and visible completely.

My attempt has ended in this

[Image](http://puu.sh/5SrKd.png)

I was able to rotate it by adding a rotate styling to the tab itself, but i cannot resize the anchorpane, or tab at all.

After googling for a long time, I could only find this http:// javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19547. It says that the only way they could do it is to "put the text into the tab's 'Graphic' to achieve this". I'm not sure what that means or how to accomplish that.

My end goal is to create tabs that have the same shape and feel as [these (image)](http://puu.sh/5SswQ.png)

Answer (score -1):

In this solution:

http://oreilly.com/pub/a/mac/2002/03/22/vertical_text.html

The text was painted vertically and tried as an icon on the tab. This way you don't have to modify JTabbedPane you just use a custom Icon in the tab.

Of course you would also have to specify the tab placement to be on the Left.